# Counting progressions for Ramsey-type number

Tags: ramsey-theory, probabilistic-method

I'm currently learning about Ramsey theory and how to use the probabilistic method to find lower bounds. Currently I'm looking at a family, which I'll call $H$, that is composed of the following families:

$AP_{a(m)} \cup AP_{m} \cup AP_{2m}$

where $AP_{a(m)}$ is the family of all a(mod m) progressions and $AP_{m}$ and $AP_{2m}$ are the families of all arithmetic progressions with gaps of fixed integers $m$ and $2m$, respectively.

How would I go about counting the the number of arithmetic progressions per the probabilistic method?

Comment: Are these progressions infinite?  Is $AP_{a(m)}$ a subset of $AP_m$?  Where do you want to count the progressions?

Comment: No, the progressions are of length k using r colors, i.e H(k;r), and I would like to count the total in [1,n]. As far as $AP_{a(m)}$ being a subset of $AP_{m}$... I want to say yes.